# Let L be the linear differential operator of order 2 given by L = D2+5xD−3. Compute L(x).

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I have no idea where to even begin with question, and my book isn't very helpful on this topic.

> [image]

Comment: The solution here (http://www.math.purdue.edu/~danielli/practprobf08.pdf) says the answer is B. But I don't think that's the correct one. (And I don't think there *is* a correct one.)

Comment: "I have no idea where to even begin with question": one can go back to the *definition* of $L(x)$. Checking your notes to see what it means may be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what they mean by $L$ is the operator
\begin{equation}
L = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + 5 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} -3 \ .
\end{equation}
Then if we apply this to $x$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
L(x) &=& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} x + 5 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x -3 x \ ,
\\
&=& 0 + 5x - 3x\ ,
\\
&=& 2x \ .
\end{eqnarray}